# Run Python Script on a remote server from another remote server using Flask and Python

Tags: python, flask

i have a flask app in a remote server which should invoke a python script store in another remote server .
i am getting an error "subprocess.CalledProcessError returned non-zero exit status 2 "

when calling python script stored in same server where the flask app is present it works fine . but when i call python script located in another remote server it shows me above error .

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
import sys
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def firstpage():
    return  "AM In"
    
@app.route('/my_function')
def index():
    s2_out = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, "\\bcp123gfrm\d$\Program\flaskt\Callfunction.py", "niranjana"])
    return  s2_out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1',debug=True)
```

**Callfunction.py inside bcp123gfrm server**

```
import sys
def main(arg):
    print("Hello "+arg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

bcp123gfrm server is windows server . am new to this microservice and flask concept . Can anyone help me on this .

Comment: I don't see any relationship to microservices here.

Comment: removed it @KlausD.